# Difference between the balance of Etherscan and wallet ethereum

Tags: etherscan

I have a problem , there is a discrepancy between Etherscan and my wallet..

https://etherscan.io/address/0x9Bd1fA1B8C1D1cED42579813A7A73B30e4078E9C

https://nanopool.org/account/0x9Bd1fA1B8C1D1cED42579813A7A73B30e4078E9C

in my wallet 8.58 ether

I'm using geth 1.4.10 and wallet 0.8.0

Comment: Is your wallet fully synced? (Perhaps try restarting it, and check that it finishes syncing any blocks that it doesn't have.)

Answer (score 0):

Etherscan indexes the blockchain and displays the data on its website.

It is possible that they could have technical issues which mean that the data on their website is not fully up to date. Alternatively it may be the case that during periods of high network traffic there is a larger than normal delay between when a block is mined and when Etherscan's backend services process it.

If you run your own node you must make sure it is fully synced. If it does not have data of every mined block (and the transactions contained within) then the balance of a given account may not be reflected correctly.